# Bitcoin.org In Inaccessible at My University

Tags: bitcoin-core, websites, bitcoin.org

Any connection to bitcoin.org from the Iowa State University campus times out (HTTP[S] and ping).  It has been this way for years and IT "doesn't know anything about why it's not working."  I've also tried contacting Black Lotus and now Level 3, but neither replied.  I can work around the block, but I don't like doing that for every update of Bitcoin Core.

How would I go about contacting someone who has the power to troubleshoot the problem from the server's end?

Comment: Were you able to eliminate campus policy as the cause. I don't think upstreams like L3 would drop a university.

Comment: I still do not know what is causing the problem.  I agree that I doubt L3 would drop multiple IP blocks from a university.  But my university IT security is quite convinced that they aren't blocking it.  The folks at bitcoin.org [said](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/1543) they will be moving off of L3 soon and quit troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but creating a ticket on the github repo for bitcoin.org is probably reasonable:  https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org

This is the code repository for the website, and not support for the server.  However, I'm guessing someone there can point you in the right direction, if not help you outright.

But what do I know?  I'm a UNI alum ;)

Comment: I followed your advice and opened an issue: https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/1543#issuecomment-290417027

They were in progress of switching off of Level 3/Black Lotus anyway, so the problem is now fixed (still can't get L3/BL though).

Comment: Glad they fixed it.